# Javascript not picking up attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Thanks to help here, I got a sample piece of code working When I tried to apply it to the real thing, something is not working quite.

In my view (new.html.erb), I have the following:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :addtl_attendee_payment, :value => Addtl_attendee_charge %>
```

(Addtl_attendee_charge comes from a config file)

and in my javascript file, I have the following:

```
function display_value() {
    var a = $("#addtl_attendee_payment");
    alert(a.val());
}
```

and in another spot in my new.html.erb, I have the following:

```
<script><%= "display_value()" %></script>
```

When I run this, I get "undefined" inside the alert box. If I look at the HTML (using firefly), here's what I get:

```
<input id="payment_addtl_attendee_payment" type="hidden" value="500" name="payment[addtl_attendee_payment]">
```

Payment is the model name. This is the same type of code that worked for the test code. Any ideas?

## Note:

Note again that the model name is Payment, and although I did not add payment to the attribute name, Rails added it automatically. I did try another variation on the javascript file:

```
function display_value() {
    var a = $("#payment_addtl_attendee_payment");
    alert(a.val());
}
```

But that did not work either (getting the same message). I think that adding the payment_ is normal and is done by Rails (but I could be wrong, being a newbie)

Answer (score 4):

Notice, you have different ID in the rendered markup:

```
var a = $("#payment_addtl_attendee_payment");
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this. I tried it both ways: addtl_attendee_payment and payment_addtl_attendee_payment. I will edit my question

Comment: @user1765002 Check that `display_value()` is executed when the DOM is loaded (i.e. inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`).

Comment: It is executed. I am getting an alert message with the following inside it: Undefined. If it's not executing, I would not be getting this message.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your ID is fixed then you can use

```
 var a = $("#payment_addtl_attendee_payment");
```

for getting the value , or you can go with this piece of code

```
 var a = $("#_addtl_attendee_payment");
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you add a unique class attribute for the hidden field and access the value through it.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :addtl_attendee_payment, :class="some_unique_class_id", :value => Addtl_attendee_charge %>
```

And you can access the value as below.

```
function display_value() {
    var a = $(".some_unique_class_id");
    alert(a.val());
}
```